# Can you help me out with this question?

Tags: number-sequence, triangle

[image]

I found that 3abc+a+b+c formula is correct first and second triangle.
But the result for third triangle isn't in the options.
Can you find another solution?

**Source:** *It's from an old job admission exam of a bank. Can not recall bank name.*

Comment: It appears you took the question from a book. Please mention the source of the question, proper attribution is necessary, otherwise the question might be closed.

Comment: it's from an old job admission exam  of a bank

Comment: you should edit the question to include the source.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is -

> D - 349

Explanation-

> it is achieved by summing the cube of the corner digits,
> as in $a^3+b^3+c^3$
>  $1^3 +2^3+ 2^3=17$
>  $3^3 +3^3+ 4^3=118$
>  $2^3 +5^3+ 6^3=349$